# Why use df["column":].str as opposed to not

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe with a string column and I want to do some filtering, what's the difference between

`df["string_column"].str.startswith(...)`

and

`df["string_column"].startswith(...)`

Both work fine for me. I'm just curious of why we use `.str`

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'startswith'` from `df["string_column"].startswith(...)` which is what I would expect. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: startswith is a method that works only on strings hence you must use .str first

Answer (score 0):

some methods are specific to string types only. such as contains(), lower(), replace()..